# Need conversion technique from Times ten dateTime to Saxon Timestamp

Tags: saxon

Trying to retrieve a dateTime Information from Timesten Database and use it in Saxon Xquery .below is the example for that and getting the below error . Do we need to convert timesten dateTime to saxom dataTime if yes how to do that ? pls help me if have idea.

let $DateVar:=fn:data($PERSON/BIRTHDAY)
where as  $PERSON/IN_BIRTHDAY is  2010-04-04 03:16:04.000000

if I am trying

let $day-b-DT :=day-from-dateTime($DateVar)

I am getting

Validation error 
  FORG0001: Invalid dateTime value "2010-04-04 03:16:04.000000" (Day must be two digits)
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiUncheckedException: Invalid dateTime value "2010-04-04 03:16:04.000000" (Day must be two digits)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is just your string format, which should be 
"2010-04-04T03:16:04.000000". See the [documentation for `dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) for more information.

I don't know anything about the Times ten database, or whether you retrieve values in a "rich" format which you happen to be *formatting* to a string (in which case you should be able to specify a different format) but I believe that's what's wrong.